# How to update \sectiontitle and \chaptertitle with \putbib and \bibliography?

Tags: natbib, titlesec, bibunits

- Pagestyles are defined with [**titlesec**](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec). A two-sided template is used, and in the main pagestyle `\chaptertitle` is shown in the header of even pages and `\sectiontitle` in the odd ones.
- [**natbib**](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) is used to allow for author citation (`\citeauthor`). In addition, the `\bibsection` command is provided, which I renewed to have `\section*{}` titles when showing partial lists and `\chapter*{}` when showing the global references list.
- [**bibunits**](http://ctan.org/pkg/bibunits) is used to define and show partial references lists.

I want `\sectiontitle` and `\chaptertitle` to be updated with `\putbib` or `\bibliography` so that the headers show `\bibname`, instead of the previous section/chapter. But, since starred variants are used, I can't get it done.

I've tried renewing them by hand just before calling `\putbib` or `\bibliography`:

```
\renewcommand{\sectiontitle}{\bibname}
\renewcommand{\chaptertitle}{\bibname}
```

but I get no difference.

Do you know how to update the headers when starred chapters or sections are created?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,10pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[]{natbib}
\usepackage[globalcitecopy]{bibunits}
\defaultbibliography{IEEEfull,IEEEexample}
\defaultbibliographystyle{IEEEtranSN}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section*{\bibname}}

\usepackage[pagestyles,explicit]{titlesec}

\newpagestyle{main}{ \headrule \footrule %head and foot rules
 \sethead[][][\chaptertitle] %head-even
 {\sectiontitle}{}{} %head-odd
 \setfoot[][\thepage][] %foot-even
 {}{\thepage}{} %foot-odd
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{main}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{main}

 \begin{bibunit}
  \chapter{Introduction}

  \lipsum[1-5] \cite{IEEEexample:article_typical}

  \section{First section}
  \cite{IEEEexample:shellCTANpage} \lipsum[1-4]

  \section{Second section}
  \lipsum[2-6] \cite{IEEEexample:IEEEwebsite} \lipsum[7-11]

  \nocite*{IEEEexample:book_typical,IEEEexample:articledualmonths}  

 \renewcommand*{\sectiontitle}{\bibname}
  \putbib
 \end{bibunit}

 \cleardoublepage
 \renewcommand{\bibsection}{\chapter*{\bibname}}
 \bibliographystyle{IEEEtranSN}
 \bibliography{IEEEfull,IEEEexample}
 \cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

I would like the headers in pages 5, 7 and 8 to display `\bibname`. Page 6 is correct, since it is the even page of the first chapter (Introduction).

---

After the answer by @cfr, y tried the next change:

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section*{\bibname}\sectionmark{\bibname}}
```

instead of

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section*{\bibname}}
```

and

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\chapter*{\bibname}\chaptermark{\bibname}}
```

instead of

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\chapter*{\bibname}}
```

And it works!

---

If **biblatex** is used instead of **natbib**, it may be accomplished with:

```
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{\chapter*{#1}\chaptermark{#1}}
\defbibheading{subbibliography}[\bibname]{\section*{#1}\sectionmark{#1}}
```

Comment: I can't compile without error due to missing `bibfile.bib`.

Comment: I've updated the question to provide it's content. You can download the remaining files (`IEEEfull.bib` and `IEEEtranSN.bst`) from [**IEEEtran/bibtex**](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex)

Comment: Lots of people won't download files just to answer questions. Fortunately, most people will have those already. You could simplify your question by sticking to references from IEEEfull.bib which everyone already has.

Comment: I've modified it to use the references in IEEEexample.bib, which is given with **IEEEtran**.

Apart from that, since **bibunits** is used, each *.aux file has to be processed. In the exmaple: `pdflatex mwe.tex | biblatex bu.aux | biblatex bu1.aux | biblatex mwe.aux | pdflatex mwe.tex | pdflatex mwe.tex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not fully tested as I can't compile the MWE properly:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,10pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[]{natbib}
\usepackage[globalcitecopy]{bibunits}
\defaultbibliography{IEEEfull,bibfile}
\defaultbibliographystyle{IEEEtranSN}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section*{\bibname}\markboth{\leftmark}{\bibname}}

\usepackage[pagestyles,explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{main}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}
  \fancyhf[reh]{\leftmark}%
  \fancyhf[loh]{\rightmark}%
  \fancyhf[cf]{\thepage}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{main}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{main}

 \begin{bibunit}
  \chapter{Introduction}

  \lipsum[1-5] \cite{schreiber86}

  \section{First section}
  \cite{hestenes58} \lipsum[1-4]

  \section{Second section}
  \lipsum[2-6] \cite{rutishauser66} \lipsum[7-10]

  \nocite{brent85,cavallaro88}

 \renewcommand*{\sectiontitle}{\bibname}
  \putbib
 \end{bibunit}

 \cleardoublepage
 \renewcommand{\bibsection}{\chapter*{\bibname}}
 \bibliographystyle{IEEEtranSN}
 \bibliography{IEEEfull,bibfile}
 \cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried this answer, but it changes many of the heads/foots I want to maintain. What I actually get with the posted MWE: `1(?), 2(chaptitle head-right), 3(sectitle head-left), 4(chaptitle head-right), 5(sectitle! head-right), 6(?), 7(empty head), 8(chaptitle! head-right)`, where ? means I don't mind, because the chapter pages will have a diferent pagestyle, and ! means I want \bibname instead. On the other hand, with the answer you posted I get the sectiontile correctly updated, but it is shown on the left part of the header & footer in both even & odd. I'd like it to be done only in odd-heads

Comment: Since I'm using titlesec, I don't have to include those `\markright` and `\markboth`, because they get mixed. However, updating `\sectionmark` and `\chaptermark` made the trick. Thank you for your example.

Comment: @U.Martinez-Corral Glad it helped. I don't know `titlesec` very well, to be honest, as I've never used it myself.