# Packages to place partial TOC, LOF, LOT, LOA and LOS in some of the chapters in a report?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, titletoc, minitoc, etoc

## Context

I'm doing a template for a Master Thesis based on the `report` class and want to achieve the following characteristics:

- a) Tikz-based titles, headers and/or footers
- b) IEEE-alphanumeric style global bibliography, `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear` citation options, and partial references lists in some chapters
- c) Customized Table Of Contents, List Of Figures, List Of Tables, List Of Algorithms and List of Symbols/acronyms; and partial TOCs, LOFs, LOTs, LOAs and LOSs in some chapters

NOTE: 'some chapters' may be chapters either in the body of the report or after `\appendix`

I have used [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) + [`natbib`](http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php) + [`bibunits`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibunits) + [`minitoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) for a quite long time, and I'm changing to [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) + [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) + `minitoc`. Thanks to some very valuable suggestions in this site [[1]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201473/how-to-update-sectiontitle-and-chaptertitle-with-putbib-and-bibliography) [[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201582/natbib-ieeetran-and-alphanumeric-citation-is-there-an-ieeetransan-style-availa) [[3]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201763/how-to-get-the-option-globalcitecopy-of-bibunits-with-biblatex) I've achieved characteristics a) and b).

## Alternatives to `minitoc`

In the documentation of `minitoc`, it is said to be incompatible with `titlesec`:

> We test the presence of the titlesec package, and emit a warning, because this package is incompatible with minitocs

All the auxuliary files (*.mtc?, *.mlf?, *.mlt?...) are correctly generated, but due to the usage of `\chapter*{}` and `\section*{}` some of the mini lists are shown in the wrong chapter. I've tried using `\addstarredchapter{}` and `\adjustptc`, and managed to get correctly placed mini lists in all the chapters before the `\appendix`. It seemed to me that I had to make many not so clear changes to the template in order to get it working, and some more 'cheats' are still needed. I think I could [hook](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=7182) `\minitoc`, but it doesn't look to be the best idea to me.

So, since `minitoc` is currently unmaintained (as commented by @Johannes_B) I've been looking for alternatives and found [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft), [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) and [`etoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc). I would pick `etoc`, because it is the newest one. But both `tocloft` and `titletoc` are closely related to `titlesec`, which I'm actually using.

*Which one would you recommend to show partial TOCs, LOFs and  LOTs in some of the chapters of a report, besides customizing their style?*

Comment: I haven't checked, but i think `minitoc` handles starred chapter/sections differently. There should be more information in the manual (section 2.30).

Comment: You are asking a lot of questions here. Hard to cover them all in an answer.

Comment: Package `minitoc` is currently (sadly) unmaintained, so i would go with etoc.

Comment: I'll try to rewrite it and make it clear.

Comment: I just finished editing the question. Hope it's easier to answer now. Thanks for your suggestion about using `etoc`.

Comment: You can give a try at `titletoc`, from the `titlesec` family.

Comment: I think @Johannes_B's concern was not so much that the questions weren't clear but that there may be too many of them for a single question. You may find you get better and quicker answers if you stick to one question per question. That way, you don't need to have somebody who can answer all of them happen along.

Comment: I think `glossaries` can handle acronyms, too. I've certainly used `glossaries` with `etoc` for partial tocs. (Not exactly mini tocs - more like cumulative tocs - but I think mini tocs are probably more straightforward, if anything.)

Comment: I've removed the last part to keep it simpler. On choosing between `etoc` and `titletoc` (since those are the ones you mentioned), I read [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163550/how-to-use-the-package-etoc-to-create-local-tocs) that `etoc` only handles Tables of Contents (nor LOFs, neither LOTs). If that is still true, I think I should pick 'titletoc'.

Comment: @U.Martinez-Corral yes `etoc` does not handle, as of its current version `1.07l [2014/04/22]`, neither LOFs nor LOTs but only TOCs.