# Check if a partial table of contents or list of figures/tables is empty before showing the title

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I've created a command, `\importchapter{<title>}{<folder>}{<file>}{<minitables>}`, to import the main `<file>` of a chapter from a `<folder>` and automatically generate a `\chapter{<title>}`.

[`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) is used to manage bibliography. A `refsegment` is created for each chapter, and `\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment]` is done at the end of `\importchapter`.

[`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) is used to place local tables of contents and/or lists of figures and/or tables in some of the chapters of a report. `startcontents`/`startlist`s are placed before importing the chapter file and `stopcontents`/`stopslist`s at the end of `\importchapter`.

Since `\printbibliography` is not shown if no citations are done, I don't have to worry about it. However, the titles of the partial tables and lists are shown even if there are no elements to show in that chapter. I decide when to show then manually putting `\DOmc`, `\DOmf` and/or `\DOmt` in the `<minitables>` parameter of `\importchapter`. But I'd like them to automatically check if there is something to show, just like `\printbibliography`.

I suppose I should look into `*.ptc`, `*.plf` and `*.plt` and check if there is any `\contentsline` between `chapter@k` and `chapter@k+1` for the kth chapter. But I have no idea about how to do it. Is it possible?

In the following example, the List of Figures should be shown only in the first chapter.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{import}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee-alphabetic,natbib=true,sorting=ynt]{biblatex} %added
\addbibresource{IEEEfull.bib} %added

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{intro.tex}
 \section{First}
  \begin{figure}[!h]\caption{First figure}\end{figure}
 \section{Second}
  \begin{figure}[!h]\caption{Second figure}\end{figure}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{back.tex}
 \section{First back}
 \subsection{First sub back}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\newcommand\DOminitoc[2]{ \section*{#1} #2 }

\newcommand\DOmc{ \DOminitoc{ \contentsname }{ \printcontents[chapter]{}{1}{} } }
\newcommand\DOmf{ \DOminitoc{ \listfigurename }{ \printlist[chapter]{lof}{1}{} } }
\newcommand\DOmt{ \DOminitoc{ \listtablename }{ \printlist[chapter]{lot}{1}{} } }

\newcommand\importchapter[4]{
 \begin{refsegment}
  \chapter{#1}
  \startcontents[chapter]
  \startlist[chapter]{lof}
  \startlist[chapter]{lot}
  #4

  \vspace{1em}\hrule
  \subimport{#2}{#3}
  \stopcontents[chapter]
  \stoplist[chapter]{lof}
  \stoplist[chapter]{lot}
  \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=subbibliography]
 \end{refsegment}
}

\begin{document}

\importchapter{Introduction}{}{intro}{\DOmc\DOmf}
\importchapter{Background}{}{back}{\DOmc\DOmf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe, this could be done much easier with `minitoc`, with some additional features, however.

Comment: I changed to `titletoc` because I 'm using `titlesec` and it is not compatible with `minitoc`. I asked about it [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202082/packages-to-place-partial-toc-lof-lot-loa-and-los-in-some-of-the-chapters-in?noredirect=1). Do you think it would be better to hook `minitoc`?