# How to change "reference" letter size

Tags: bibliographies, fontsize

I use

```
 \bibliographystyle{abbrv}
 {\small \bibliography{reference}}
```

for references. How can I change the size of the "Reference" letter?
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc. Why do you use the `biblatex` tag?

Comment: Do you want to change the font size of the entries or the title or both? I assume it's not just one letter!

Answer (score 3):

[Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

The bibliography uses either `\chapter*` or `\section*`, depending on the class you use. You can rewrite them as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22645/hiding-the-title-of-the-bibliography). However, if you are using any package such as [`natbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) or [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), you can [explicitly define it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201473/how-to-update-sectiontitle-and-chaptertitle-with-putbib-and-bibliography). Say you are using `article` and want to have it displayed as a subsection:

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\subsection*{\bibname}} %natbib
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{\subsection*{#1}} %biblatex
```

Since the better approach depends on the packages you are actually using, as @Aradnix commented, it would be easier to get waht you need if you provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).